# Find the point of $f^{-1}$ corresponding to the value of x indicated

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

i am having problems understanding this problem.

The given function $f$ is one-to-one. Find $f^{-1}$, find the point on the graph of $f^{-1}$ corresponding to the indicated value of $x$ in the domain of $f$.

$f(x) = 2x^3 + 2x; x = 2$

Comment: This seems somewhat ambiguous; it may be asking for the value of $f^{-1}(2)$, or it may be asking for the point $(f(2),2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = f(x) = 2x^3 + 2x$. But, $f(2) = 2\cdot 2^3 + 2\cdot 2 = 20$. Thus, $(20,2)$ is the point on the graph of $f^{-1}$.